# Significance test for influence of factor (with many levels of unequal size) and a binary dependent variable

Tags: r

In real life, I try to predict the state of health of a vehicle based on numerous fault codes.

Some fault codes (levels of the factor) appear very often (1000+), others occur only two or three times. Often, those that appear very infrequently are "perfect predictors" of the health state (0 or 1). I am trying to find a sound statistical way to decide which of the levels of the factors are good predictors (significant). This in a way that infrequent fault codes that are good predictors are not discarded based on their infrequency alone.

### Data Creation

```
library(tidyverse)
n_small =   4
n_big   = 100

set.seed(567)
df_big_1 <- data.frame(class = rep("A", n_big),
                       health = rbinom(n = n_big, size = 1, prob = .4))
df_small_1 <- data.frame(class = rep("B", n_small),
                         health = rbinom(n = n_small, size = 1, prob = 1))
df_small_2 <- data.frame(class = rep("C", n_small), 
                         health = rbinom(n = n_small, size = 1, prob = 1))
df_big_2 <- data.frame(class = rep("D", n_big),
                       health = rbinom(n = n_big, size = 1, prob = .4))
df_big_3 <- data.frame(class = rep("E", n_big),
                       health = rbinom(n = n_big, size = 1, prob = .4))
df_data <- rbind(df_big_1 ,df_small_1, df_big_2, df_small_2, df_big_3)
df_data <- df_data %>% mutate(class = factor(class))
```

### Inspection of data

```
df_data %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  summarise(N_health = sum(health), Mean = mean(health))
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  class N_health  Mean
  <fct>    <int> <dbl>
1 A           36  0.36
2 B            4  1   
3 C            4  1   
4 D           40  0.4 
5 E           40  0.4
```

### (Binary) Logistic Regression

When I run a binary logistic regression on this simplified data set, I fail to retrieve the infrequent but "perfect" predictors:

```
regmod_01 <- glm(health ~ class, family = binomial, data = df_data)
summary(regmod_01

Call:
glm(formula = health ~ class, family = binomial, data = df_data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.0108  -1.0108  -0.9448   1.3537   1.4294  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)   -0.5754     0.2083  -2.762  0.00575 **
classB        17.1414  1199.7724   0.014  0.98860   
classC        17.1414  1199.7724   0.014  0.98860   
classD         0.1699     0.2917   0.583  0.56022   
classE         0.1699     0.2917   0.583  0.56022   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 415.22  on 307  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 399.89  on 303  degrees of freedom
AIC: 409.89

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 15
```

Is there another way that I can try to separate the good from the bad predictors and include infrequent ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have a bit of a misunderstanding regarding what the p-value is telling you. That metric tells you how *reliable* your results are. Your variable could fail to explain anything about the outcome variable and be significant. Let's say the variable has essentially no impact, but its *p*-value is .01. That tells you if someone redid that analysis with a sample from the same population as your data, 99 out of 100 times they'll get the same result that you did... that the variable tells you nothing about the outcome.

I'm not sure how dedicated you are to that analysis method or the commonly misunderstood *p*-value. I think you should look at survival ensembles (when you include a time component) or decision-based classifiers.

For example, if I make your outcome variable a factor and use `caret` & `randomForest`, it tells me that classes B and C are the most influential (`importance`) in your dataset. `varImp()` provides this information.

For example (using the outcomes below), the `B` class mean decrease in accuracy is 16.306. If you exclude this class, the accuracy will decrease by over 16%. The classes `E` and `D` have negative results. This indicates that if you didn't include these classes, your accuracy would improve.

For this to work, you need to install the package `randomForest`. You don't need to call the library, though.

Check it out:

```
library(caret) 
    
df_data$health <- factor(df_data$health)

set.seed(3253)
tr <- createDataPartition(df_data$health, p = .7, list = F)

cfit <- train(health~., data = df_data[tr, ], importance = T, keep.forest = T)

varImp(cfit, scale = F)  # mean decrease in accuracy
# rf variable importance
# 
#        Importance
# classB     16.306
# classC     11.287
# classE     -0.967
# classD     -2.036 

varImp(cfit, type = 2)  # mean increase in purity
# rf variable importance
# 
#        Overall
# classB  100.00
# classC   57.21
# classD    0.60
# classE    0.00
```

There are a lot of decision tree-based methods of analysis. One benefit of a random forest is its lack of almost any formal statistical assumptions and the inability to overfit. The same can be said for many decision tree-based methods, but not all.

Comment: Perfect/near-perfect predictors should have very low if not zero p-values. The high p-values despite perfect separation are due to the Hauck-Donner effect, and are a statistical error of the default Wald's test.

Comment: @Kat where can I learn more about p-values vs. variable importance? This confusion around p-values is why I'm moving towards more robust methods such as quantile regressions

Comment: Well, p-values are entirely unrelated to importance. I'd be really surprised if you found something that compares them.  [Some info on the p-vlaue](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-understand-p-value-in-layman-terms-80a5cc206ec2). For variable importance and similar measures, [check out this information](https://topepo.github.io/caret/variable-importance.html) Look 15.1.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic instance of what is referred to in statistics as the Hauck-Donner effect.

From [McMaster University](https://math.mcmaster.ca/%7Ebolker/classes/s4c03/notes/week5.pdf), credits to @BenBolker:

> The Hauck-Donner effect occurs in cases of extreme parameter estimates (e.g. in the case of complete or near-complete separation),
> when the quadratic approximation is extremely poor: the hallmark is
> large parameter estimates (e.g. |βˆ| > 10) and very large confidence
> intervals (leading to small Z statistics and large p values).

The predictors classB and classC being infrequent is **not** the cause for why their p-values are far higher than you may expect. If you repeat your exact code with n_small as 90 instead of 5, classB and classC still have those high p-values of 0.98.

```r
n_small =   90
...
regmod_01 <- glm(health ~ class, family = binomial, data = df_data)
summary(regmod_01)


Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)   -0.5754     0.2083  -2.762  0.00575 **
classB        20.1414  1133.5725   0.018  0.98582   
classC        20.1414  1133.5725   0.018  0.98582   
classD         0.1699     0.2917   0.583  0.56022   
classE         0.1699     0.2917   0.583  0.56022
```

**However**, if you marginally decrease the probability for B and C from perfectly 1 to 0.97 instead and keep the n_small at 90, the p-values change dramatically from almost 1.00 to incredibly significant (p<0.001), as Wald's test starts functioning properly again.

```r
n_small =   90
...
df_small_1 <- data.frame(class = rep("B", n_small),
                         health = rbinom(n = n_small, size = 1, prob = 0.97))
df_small_2 <- data.frame(class = rep("C", n_small), 
                         health = rbinom(n = n_small, size = 1, prob = 0.97))
...
regmod_01 <- glm(health ~ class, family = binomial, data = df_data)
summary(regmod_01)

              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -5.754e-01  2.083e-01  -2.762  0.00575 ** 
classB       5.064e+00  1.027e+00   4.931 8.18e-07 ***
classC       3.943e+00  6.231e-01   6.328 2.49e-10 ***
classD       3.779e-15  2.946e-01   0.000  1.00000    
classE       4.315e-02  2.938e-01   0.147  0.88323
```

The p-values obtained in standard glm output are via the Wald's test, which is known to be wildly unreliable in cases of extreme separation (perfect predictors). The likelihood ratio test (LRT) is a more suitable alternative in these cases especially for binomial regression.

`glm` currently has no built-in Hauck-Donner effect detection support. However, if we repeat this test with `VGAM::vglm`, we see an appropriate warning message at the bottom:

```r
library(VGAM)

regmod_01 <- VGAM::vglm(health ~ class, family = binomialff, data = df_data)
summary(regmod_01)

(output)

Warning: Hauck-Donner effect detected in the following estimate(s):
'classB', 'classC'
```

To answer your question, you could go with the factors that have a significant p-value, as well as any factors with a coefficient/estimate of above 10 or below 0.1, which may not register as significant on the Wald test but in reality are very significant.

Keep in mind that the p-values for each factor level are in reference to the intercept level in a dummy contrast coding scheme, so depending on what you choose as the reference significance and odds ratios may vary widely. It is better to use a Likelihood Ratio test to determine the significance of the whole variable, not individuals levels, in the regression model.

Comment: Very interesting. I wonder however how this approach would be useful when there are many small factor levels that are in reality not important. For example imagine a factor consisting of 100 levels, each with 2 observations generated at random. You'd see that half of them seem to be perfect predictors even though we know that's not the case.

Comment: @IyarLin Such data isn't well suited for statistical inference in general, and coefficients don't speak much at all in that case regardless of the method. Perhaps one should add a custom sample size cutoff or criteria. But then again, the Wald's p-values and coefficients are all relative to the reference level and can be replaced by more robust tests such as likelihood estimation. I merely suggest a general rule of thumb, which can in many cases be superseded by common sense.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking when one considers the relation between a given factor level and the predicted variable you can measure 2 often contradicting measures:

1. The level "predictive accruacy"
2. The level frequency

The smaller a class level is - the higher it would seem highly predictive just by chance. Consider for example 100 class levels, each with only 2 observations **generated at random**. You'll see that about half of the levels "perfectly" predict the outcome (sometimes pure 0s, sometimes pure 1s) even though there's no real relation. That's why you're also seeing high p-values in your regression.

A very natural way of deciding which class levels have high predictive value, and by extension what variables in general have high predictive value is to use a [conditional inference tree](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partykit/vignettes/ctree.pdf).

This type of tree uses a permutation test that takes into account not only the predictive accuracy but also the size of each class level. You can see in the linked vignette more how this type of tree is different to the classic CART in that regard.

In your dataset we get:

```
library(partykit)
treemod <- ctree(health ~ class, data = df_data)
treemod

Fitted party:
[1] root
|   [2] class in A, D, E: 0.387 (n = 300, err = 71.1)
|   [3] class in B, C: 1.000 (n = 8, err = 0.0)

Number of inner nodes:    1
Number of terminal nodes: 2
```

You can see that the tree did find the 2 "infrequent" levels like you expected. You can also see from the tree structure that levels A,D and E are not different enough from each other to be considered separately.

To see how useful this approach is, let's go to the example of 100 class levels with 2 randomly generated observations each:

```
df_data2 <- data.frame(class = factor(rep(1:100, each = 2)), 
                      health = rbinom(n = 200, size = 1, prob = 0.5))
```

Below we run the tree again and see that it made no splits (meaning no factors are important) just like we wanted it to:

```
treemod2 <- ctree(health ~ class, data = df_data2)
treemod2

Fitted party:
[1] root: 0.530 (n = 200, err = 49.8) 

Number of inner nodes:    0
Number of terminal nodes: 1
```